# what java collection that provides multiple values for the same key

Tags: java, collections

what type of java collection that returns multiple values for the same key?

example, I want to return 301,302,303 for key 300.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a `List` as the value of your `Map`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(301);
list.add(302);
list.add(303);

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
map.put(300, list);

map.get(300); // [301,302,303]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Guava, as suggested by biziclop, which has a much cleaner syntax, and lots of other very useful utility methods:

```
Multimap<Integer, Integer> map = HashMultimap.create();
map.put(300, 301);
map.put(300, 302);
map.put(300, 303);

Collection<Integer> list = map.get(300); // [301, 302, 303]
```

Comment: The advantage of a multimap over this solution is that you can add single elements to any key without checking whether there is already a list there. Sometimes this doesn't matter but often it does.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes I do get tired of writing that same old code that verifies if there already exists a collection for a given key, and creating a new one if it doesn't. Guava's `Multimap` does a great job simplifying that, but I tend to like the concept of having a `Map` for which `put(key, value)` simply overrides the existing value for a key.

Comment: It all depends on what you really need, and the question is far too laconic to decide.

Answer (score 8):

You could use Multimap, it is under the Apache license.

See [this link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html). For posterity:

```
org.apache.commons.collections
Interface MultiMap

All Superinterfaces:
    java.util.Map

All Known Implementing Classes:
    MultiHashMap, MultiValueMap

public interface MultiMap
extends java.util.Map

Defines a map that holds a collection of values against each key.

A MultiMap is a Map with slightly different semantics. Putting a value into the map will add the value to a Collection at that key. Getting a value will return a Collection, holding all the values put to that key.

For example:

 MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
 mhm.put(key, "A");
 mhm.put(key, "B");
 mhm.put(key, "C");
 Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);

coll will be a collection containing "A", "B", "C".
```

Comment: And a generic version: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: biziclop yes nice suggestion you shoud add this as another answer so you get points and free beer

Comment: I don't mind the points much. But that free beer sounds very tempting. :)

Comment: What are the advantages of using a Multimap as opposed to a map whose values are lists, as suggested above?

Comment: Its syntax is much simpler, and has lots of useful utility methods. However, internally, it's implemented pretty much in the same way.

Comment: @GravityBringer: One obvious answer is, that if you use a Map+List combination that you either (1) have to add a List to each and every entry OR (2) have to make special cases for entry-is-empty VS. entry-is-single-item VS. entry-is-list (and have to update accordingly) and always have to make these special cases. What's more: Multimaps are can be (and in most implementations are) optimized: The implementor knows what you intend to do with the object, it avoids List allocation-deallocation and there are other optimizations for speed.

Answer (score 1):

1. As mentioned in a comment above above there is always Guava Multimap
   http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html
2. Apache Commons Collections 4 has Generic version of MultiMap  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html
3. JAX-RS specifies a MultivaluedMap interface which is implemented by all JAX-RS Providers.
   If your use case is within the context of a JAX-RS REST Service/Client, it would be an option to use their implementation without pulling in another dependency.

   javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap (each JAX RS Provider has their own implementation)